# How to add Pre Deployment and Post deployment approvals in multistage YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-deployment, multistage-pipeline

I have a Multistage YAML pipeline containing two stages 1) Build and 2) Deploy. Deploy stage is mentioned below and I want to add pre deploy approvals in that stage before deploy task. How can I add pre deployment and Post deployment approvals in multistage YAML pipeline?

```
stages:
- stage: 'Build'

# RESTORE
   # Some task implementation
# BUILD
   # Some task implementation
# PUBLISH
   # Some task implementation

# DEPLOY STAGE
- stage: 'Dev'
  displayName: 'Deploy to the dev environment'
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
    environment: dev
    variables:
    - group: Release
    strategy:

# HOW TO ADD PRE DEPLOYMENT AND POST DEPLOYMENT APPROVALS?

      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Resource Manager - Tailspin - Space Game'
              appName: '$(WebAppNameDev)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(buildConfiguration)/*.zip'
```

Comment: Did you figure out a way to set post deployment approvals? Me too having same problem.

Comment: No buddy. I haven't. I found out that using YAML/YML we can only set one approval which is Pre-approval. Which we can set on any Environment we want and the approval window will be shown to the user added as an approver. This is all I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this issue ,currently, manual approval and evaluate artifact are the only available checks, and they can be configured on **environments**, service connections and agent pools only.

To define an approval on an environment:

1. In your Azure DevOps project, go to the environment that needs to be protected. (Learn more about [creating an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#creation).)

   [image]
2. Navigate to **Approvals and Checks** for the environment.

   [image]
3. Select Create, provide the approvers and an optional message, and select Create again to to complete addition of the manual approval check.

Then use the `environment: 'xxx'` parameter in your yaml file. For example:

```
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 'multiStage'
```

The GUI and the yaml are interdependent in this case, it's not straight yaml.

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to setup post deployment approvals? your help is much appreciated.